# Can not retrieve a url using curl

Tags: curl

While trying to retrieve the URL  http://www.kat.ph/search/snow-patrol-shut-your-eyes/?categories%5B%5D=music 
using curl I am getting an error which says

> curl: (3) [globbing] illegal character in range specification at pos 65

Why is that so ? while [ seems to be a perfectly valid character in the browser address bar ,how can i retrieve the same url in curl ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curl http://www.kat.ph/search/snow-patrol-shut-your-eyes/?categories%5B%5D=music`

works fine for me. Is that actually what you're using? Or do you have the [ in your curl string?

Update

Yeah, I get the same error on `curl http://www.kat.ph/search/snow-patrol-shut-your-eyes/?categories[]=music`. Your browser silently encodes the [] for you when it makes the request (browsers allow users to be lazy). cURL expects you to be able to encode for yourself, so characters like [], space, etc. need to be encoded first. Take a look at this tool to encode or decode a URL http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 8):

You can use the -g option to stop curl from globbing itself. It will then pass the URL with [] to the server as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the [  and ] characters as follows `\[` and `\]`

Comment: You'll get the same error: 
`preinheimer@washington:~$ curl http://www.kat.ph/search/snow-patrol-shut-your-eyes/?categories\[\]=music 
curl: (3) [globbing] illegal character in range specification at pos 65`